# How to ask: Named group from where they are in the world?

Tags: questions, interrogatives

How to ask the question in right grammar:

1. <Group A> is from where in the world?
   or
2. From which country <Group A> in the world?
   or
3. <Group A> is from?

I need it as I writing a quite

Answer (score 3):

I think the most common ways of saying this would be

> Where is <Group A> from?
>   What country is <Group A> from?

Comment: what about :
Which country is Group A from?
Which part of the world is Group A from?

Comment: <Group A> is usually a plural noun phrase; the verb changes to match.  For example, "Where are the Sicilians from?" or "What country are the Sicilians from?"